# How to make ajax call of a sample json structure with loop and to put into a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I have a sample json structure.what I need is to call the json with each/for loop and to put into a variable.while calling I need the output in this format like 
parent1 = child11 child12, parent2 = child2, parent3 = child3, that depends upon the value.And then I need to put this format into a variable inside success function of ajax call itself to console it.Is there any solution for this,can anyone please help me.Below is the code and also I have updated the code into the following plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/KhFhW4Z3Kk4QwvRDr1pX?p=preview

### html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<div class="col-md-3" id="leftNavBar">

</div>
```

### script

```
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: '1.json',
      success: function(result) {

        //console.log(newvalue);
      }

    });
```

### 1.json

```
[{
    "name": "parent1",
    "value": ["child11", "child12"]
}, {
    "name": "parent2",
    "value": ["child2"]
}, {
    "name": "parent3",
    "value": ["child3"]
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can get expected result by the following code.
plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/eAS2nv5QCURtdsqphSqO?p=preview

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: '1.json',
  success: function(result) {
    var parents = {};
    $.each(result, function(index, parent) {
      parents[parent.name] = parent.value.join(' ');
    });

    console.log(parents['parent1']);  // child11 child12
    console.log(parents['parent2']);  // child2
    console.log(parents['parent3']);  // child3
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but here I need like parent1 = child11 child12, parent2 = child2, parent3 = child3  depends on the json value within sigle variable and parent1,parent2,parent3 can be different also that will comes from database,here only 'name' and 'value' will be constant

Comment: Its done..I have updated the code in this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/KhFhW4Z3Kk4QwvRDr1pX?p=preview

Comment: wow, that is very different my imagine... I thought you want to create variables from `name` key.
http://plnkr.co/edit/CQVvdvWPmFBY5yBvZRkx?p=preview

Comment: But I have one more issue here http://plnkr.co/edit/KhFhW4Z3Kk4QwvRDr1pX?p=preview that if I use alert I should get all the value at a time but its showing one by one,can you please help me on it,because I need to render these value in highchart title,there I am getting last parent child value only

Comment: I think you should post it as other question and add explanations that anybody can understand your want output.